# How to create an Expression builder in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iqueryable, linq-expressions

I have written some code to allow filtering of products on our website, and I am getting a pretty bad code smell. The user can select 1-* of these filters which means I need to be specific with the `WHERE` clause.

I think I am looking for a way to build up a lambda expression, so for every filter I can 'modify' my `WHERE` clause - but I am not sure how to do this in .NET, and there must be a way.

Code in its current state (effectively hardcoded, not dynamic, would be a pain to add more filter options).

```
public static class AgeGroups
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int> Items = new Dictionary<string, int>(){
        { "Modern (Less than 10 years old)", 1 },
        { "Retro (10 - 20 years old)", 2 },
        { "Vintage(20 - 70 years old)", 3 },
        { "Antique(70+ years old)", 4 }
    };

    public static IQueryable<ProductDTO> FilterAgeByGroup(IQueryable<ProductDTO> query, List<string> filters)
    {
        var values = new List<int>();
        var currentYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;
        foreach (var key in filters)
        {
            var matchingValue = Items.TryGetValue(key, out int value);

            if (matchingValue)
            {
                values.Add(value);
            }
        }

        if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 1 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 10);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 2 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 10 && x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 20);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 3 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 20 && x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 70);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 4 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 70);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 1, 2}))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 20);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 1, 3 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 10 || (x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 20 && x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 70));
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 1, 4 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 10 ||  x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 70);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 2, 3 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 10 && x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 70);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 2, 4 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => (x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 10 && x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 20) 
                                     || x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 70);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 70);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 1, 2, 4 }))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 20 || x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 70);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 2, 3, 4}))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 10);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 1, 3, 4}))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 10 || x.YearManufactured <= 20);
        }
        else if (Utility.EqualsIgnoringOrder(values, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }))
        {
            // all
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/#creating-expression-trees-by-using-the-api

Comment: [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) is a good tool for helping with this, but if your conditions are all anded together, you can simply chain the `Where` results for each sub-filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've recently run into this issue myself. Through the help of another question on SO I found http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx. Basically you want to build a predicate and pass that into the where clause of your query.

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> where1, 
     Expression<Func<T, bool>> where2)
{
    InvocationExpression invocationExpression = Expression.Invoke(where2, 
         where1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(where1.Body, 
         invocationExpression), where1.Parameters);
}

public static IQueryable<ProductDTO> FilterAgeByGroup(IQueryable<ProductDTO> query,  
   List<string> filters, int currentYear)
{
    var values = new HashSet<int>();
    //Default value
    Expression<Func<ProductDTO, bool>> predicate = (ProductDTO) => false;

    foreach (var key in filters)
    {
        var matchingValue = Items.TryGetValue(key, out int value);

        if (matchingValue)
        {
            values.Add(value);
        }
    }

    if (values.Count == 0)
        return query;

    if (values.Contains(1))
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 10);
    }

    if (values.Contains(2))
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 10 && 
            x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 20);
    }

    if (values.Contains(3))
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 20 && 
            x.YearManufactured >= currentYear - 70);
    }

    if (values.Contains(4))
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.YearManufactured <= currentYear - 70);
    }

    return query.Where(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the article made sense to me and this solution leverages my existing code and doesn't require any third party libraries.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you faced combinatorial explosion. You may declare simple cases statically with modified `Items` collection:

```
static Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<int, int, bool>>> Items
   = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<int, int, bool>>>
{
    {
      "Modern (Less than 10 years old)",
      (yearManufactured, currentYear) => yearManufactured >= currentYear - 10
    },
    {
      "Retro (10 - 20 years old)",
      (yearManufactured, currentYear) => yearManufactured <= currentYear - 10 && yearManufactured >= currentYear - 20
    },
    {
      "Vintage(20 - 70 years old)",
      (yearManufactured, currentYear) => yearManufactured <= currentYear - 20 && yearManufactured >= currentYear - 70
    },
    {
      "Antique(70+ years old)",
      (yearManufactured, currentYear) => yearManufactured <= currentYear - 70
    }
};
```

Now you can dynamically combine your simple cases with Linq Expression `OrElse`. Try this code:

```
public static IQueryable<ProductDTO> FilterAgeByGroup(
  IQueryable<ProductDTO> query, List<string> filters)
{
    var conditions = new List<Expression>();
    foreach (var key in filters)
        if (Items.TryGetValue(key, out Expression<Func<int, int, bool>> value))
            conditions.Add(value);

    // return as is if there no conditions
    if (!conditions.Any())
        return query;

    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ProductDTO), "x");
    var yearManufactured = Expression.PropertyOrField(x, "YearManufactured");
    var currentYear = Expression.Constant(DateTime.UtcNow.Year);
    var body = conditions.Aggregate(
        (Expression) Expression.Constant(false), // ignore item by default
        (c, n) => Expression.OrElse(c, Expression.Invoke(n, yearManufactured, currentYear)));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ProductDTO, bool>>(body, x);
    return query.Where(lambda);
}
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot because you're keeping the predicate mapped to the dictionary for an easy point of reference. The only problem is I do need to utilise the value (i.e the int) for other parts of my application

Comment: @KrishanPatel You can create dictionary `Dictionary<string, Tuple<Expression, int>>`  and with linq method `ToDictionary` modify type of value to get original dictionary from question

Comment: Do LINQ providers support `InvocationExpression`? I seem to recall that EF6 doesn't support it.

Comment: But this can be done without `Expression.Invoke` -- see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54777179/111794).

Answer (score 1):

Using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), you can easily combine the predicates. Also, there is no reason to translate the `filters` `List` to another `List` just to process them once you can combine them, you just add each filter passed in.

```
public static class AgeGroups {
    public static Dictionary<string, int> Items = new Dictionary<string, int>(){
        { "Modern (Less than 10 years old)", 1 },
        { "Retro (10 - 20 years old)", 2 },
        { "Vintage(20 - 70 years old)", 3 },
        { "Antique(70+ years old)", 4 }
    };

    public static IQueryable<ProductDTO> FilterAgeByGroup(IQueryable<ProductDTO> query, List<string> filters) {
        var currentYear = DateTime.UtcNow.Year;

        var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<ProductDTO>();
        foreach (var fs in filters) {
            if (Items.TryGetValue(fs, out var fv)) {
                switch (fv) {
                    case 1:
                        pred = pred.Or(p => currentYear-p.YearManufactured < 10);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        pred = pred.Or(p => 10 <= currentYear-p.YearManufactured && currentYear-p.YearManufactured  <= 20);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pred = pred.Or(p => 20 <= currentYear-p.YearManufactured && currentYear-p.YearManufactured  <= 70);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        pred = pred.Or(p => 70 <= currentYear-p.YearManufactured);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return query.Where(pred);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach as LINQKit looks like a useful library, and it keeps the code easier to read. However I would rather not include a separate library for only needing to use one feature, but thank you for bringing LINQKit to my attention.

Comment: @KrishanPatel You can create your own version of LINQKit's `Or` operator pretty easily, though the start value handling is a tiny bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest dynamically constructing the expression you're going to pass into the `Where` (as in [AlexAndreev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54698356/111794); but without using any compiler-generated expressions, only the factory methods in `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`.

Define first your original dictionary with a value tuple of minimum and maximum ages for each criterion:

```
// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

public static Dictionary<string, (int code, int? min, int? max)> Items = new Dictionary<string, (int code, int? min, int? max)>(){
    { "Modern (Less than 10 years old)", (1, null, 10) },
    { "Retro (10 - 20 years old)", (2, 10, 20) },
    { "Vintage(20 - 70 years old)", (3, 20, 70) },
    { "Antique(70+ years old)", (4, 70, null) }
};
```

Then you can dynamically build the predicate, adding conditions based on the passed-in filters and their matching criteria:

```
public static IQueryable<ProductDTO> FilterAgeByGroup(
    IQueryable<ProductDTO> query, 
    List<string> filters)
{
    var criteria = filters
        .Select(filter => {
            Items.TryGetValue(filter, out var criterion);
            return criterion; // if filter is not in Items.Keys, code will be 0
        })
        .Where(criterion => criterion.code > 0) // excludes filters not matched in Items
        .ToList();

    if (!criteria.Any()) { return query; }

    var type = typeof(ProductDTO);
    var x = Parameter(t);

    // creates an expression that represents the number of years old this ProductDTO is:
    // 2019 - x.YearManufactured
    var yearsOldExpr = Subtract(
        Constant(DateTime.UtcNow.Year),
        Property(x, t.GetProperty("YearManufactured"))
    );

    var filterExpressions = new List<Expression>();

    foreach (var criterion in criteria) {
        Expression minExpr = null;
        if (criterion.min != null) {
            // has to be at least criteria.min years old; eqivalent of:
            // 2019 - x.YearManufactured >= 10
            minExpr = GreaterThanOrEqual(
                yearsOldExpr,
                Constant(criterion.min)
            );
        }

        Expression maxExpr = null;
        if (criterion.max != null) {
            // has to be at least criteria.max years old; equivalent of
            // 2019 - x.YearManufactured <= 20
            maxExpr = LessThanOrEqual(
                yearsOldExpr,
                Constant(criterion.max)
            )
        }

        if (minExpr != null && maxExpr != null) {
            filterExpressions.Add(AndAlso(minExpr, maxExpr));
        } else {
            filterExpressions.Add(minExpr ?? maxExpr); // They can't both be null; we've already excluded that possibility above
        }
    }

    Expression body = filterExpressions(0);
    foreach (var filterExpression in filterExpressions.Skip(1)) {
        body = OrElse(body, filterExpression);
    }
    return query.Where(
        Lambda<Func<ProductDTO, bool>>(body, x)
    );
}
```