# The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

I have C# application (.NET Core 3.1) and I have written the following LINQ expression.

```
public ActionResult<bool> GetItems(string title)
{
     var items = _service.All.GetItems().OrderByDescending(o => o.Id).Where(w => w.Portal_Id == 1);

     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
     {
            var terms = title.Split(' ').ToList();
            items = items.Where(w => terms.Any(a => w.ItemName.Contains(a)));
     }
     // Some Other code
     return Ok();
}
```

whenever this expression is executed i get the following error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<PosItem>\r\n    .Where(p => !(p.IsDeleted))\r\n    
.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedAt)\r\n    .Where(p => p.Portal_Id == 1)\r\n    .Where(p => __terms_1\r\n      
.Any(a => p.ItemName.Contains(a)))' could not be translated.

Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by 
inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."
```

I cannot add ToList() and switch to client evaluation because the data set is too big to do so.

Please advise how can I resolve this issue without switching to client evaluation.

Thanks

Comment: Certain function calls can be translated to SQL according to this [table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#string-functions). In your particular case and without any coding whatsoever, I think you need the problem is with `items.Where(w => terms.Any(a => w.ItemName.Contains(a)))`. You are testing a client-side array.

Comment: It is likely failing to translate the `terms.Any()`. You could create an `Expression` using an `ExpressionBuilder` and a for/foreach and then use the newly created `Expression` in the `items.Where(your_new_expression)`

Comment: This answer has an example on how you could do it [How to create an Expression builder in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54698694/2265446)

Comment: Most likely it does not work, because of Contains method

Comment: You mentioned that the data is large so you want to avoid doing any client-side processing. As has been pointed out in multiple places here, using `Contains()` will result in one or more `LIKE '%item%'` terms in the final SQL query. In turn, this could easily execute as a [table scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan) on the server. That might or might not be a price worth paying.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to do a `string.Contains` within an `Any` expression which EF will choke on trying to compose down to SQL.  Cleptus is on the nose, to build a predicate for the `Where` clause OR-ing the term comparisons. Otherwise your code should work *without* the contains check, but rather an equality check:

Without `Contains`: (equality check rather than `LIKE %name%`)

```
var terms = title.Split(' ').ToList();
items = items.Where(w => terms.Contains(w.ItemName)); // IN clause.
```

Built expression:

```
var terms = title.Split(' ').ToList();
Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate = (Item) => false;
foreach(var term in terms)
    predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.ItemName.Contains(term));

items = items.Where(predicate);
```

So for each term in the title, we OR a match using a LIKE %term% on the ItemName.

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestion.
I made some changes to your solution a bit and used
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Item>(false);
and i worked

Comment: Would this work with LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also occur when using multiple ParameterExpression in one single Expression. Always transmit den ParameterExpression instance to all Expression.Property(argPara, "Name") values.

Comment: Not related to the question: they aren't building expressions here.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answer makes a whole lot of sense outside of the context that you intended. Please consider revising your answer with some more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Actually i have different solution, this works on sql,nosql (cosmos db) also
I was having query like below & error also,
[image]
For this I tried many but nothing worked properly except time-waste...final simple solution is adding AsEnumerable() to result like below,
[image]
Even if you add like below wont workout.
[image]
The reason is ,(Red) fails because it tries to run on server itself,which same error.
Insteadd grean is, you are taking Main Medicine()  and then in memory you are iterating logic with filters.so its fine.
So simple but place matters...
keep coding... keep smiling...

Comment: That pulls an entire table into memory. Also, code should not be posted as images.