# Getting exception while trying to compare enum(converted to string) and a string value obtained from search

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Getting

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable()

while trying to compare two values - an enum(by converting to string) and a string `keyword` which I get from a search form in .NET 3 API

```
 query = query.Where(it => it.EnumType.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(keyword.ToLower());
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737681/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated-either-rewrite-the-query-in-a-form

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this

```
it => it.EnumType.ToString()
```

I would suggest you do it the other way around by try converting

```
keyword.ToLower()
```

to enum.
You can try something like this.

```
private static bool IsDefined<T>(string value)
{
    return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), value);
}
public static T GetEnumByString<T>(string value)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
}
```

and then write the expression like this:

```
if (IsDefined<YourEnum>(keyword))
{
    query = query.Where(it => it.EnumType == GetEnumByString<YourEnum>(keyword)); 
}
```