# How to use DayOfWeek on a datetime in a LINQ Query on .Net CORE

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to use `DayOfWeek` in a **LINQ** query but it doesn't work.
I am using framework .Net Core 6

I have tried:

```
var test =  await _context.DailyConsumption.Where(t => t.Time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToListAsync();
```

--

```
var test =  await _context.DailyConsumption.Where(t => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Time).Value.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToListAsync();
```

and

```
DateTime firstDate = new DateTime(1753, 1, 7);
var test =  _context.DailyConsumption.Where(t => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstDate, t.Time) % 7 == 1).ToListAsync();
```

The 3 lines of code above gives me the same result:

```
InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<DailyConsumption>().Where(d => (int)d.Time.DayOfWeek == 0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'
```

My program can't even translate the code into an SLQ request, I don't understand why.

According to some sources on the internet, DayOfWeek must be used differently in .NET Core framework.
I'm stuck, there are not many people with this problem ...

EDIT :
If it can help, Here is my model :

```
 [Keyless]
public partial class DailyConsumption
{
    public string Prm { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public float Power { get; set; }
    public float PowerConsumption { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What type is `t.Time`? Is it a `DateTime`?

Comment: Yes it is a dateTime, I just added the model I use to my question

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737681/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated-either-rewrite-the-query-in-a-form, looks like the issue is that you can't use `Where` in its normal form with Entity Framework.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271588/entity-framework-dayofweek

Comment: @ScottHannen No, this answer does not help me because the person does not use net core.

Comment: @frankM_DN This answer doesn't help me anymore, I tried to generate my clause where as they do but it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that implicit client evaluation has been disabled from EF Core 3.

You can switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to `AsEnumerable` like below:

```
var test =  _context.DailyConsumption.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(t => t.Time.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday).ToList();
```

Comment: Just note that this will be executed in memory and not in the DB. So all `DailyConsumption` will be loaded by EF before applying the `Where` clause and materializing the enumeration with `ToList()`